# How to delete the effect of a commit via PR?

Tags: git, azure-devops, branching-and-merging

**TL;DR:** I need to delete a commit from master, which must be done with a pull request. How is this done?

There is a commit on master which needs to be removed because the changes it provides are bad. I cannot push a commit directly to master because of the branch policy.

I have created a branch from master and used `git reset HEAD~1` to remove the latest commit. Now the branch comparison shows my new branch being 1 commit behind master, so it will not allow me to create a pull request.

How do I remove the commit from master with a pull request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't rewrite history using a Pull Request, you'll be prevented to do things that cause a force-push.

Instead, you can add a new commit that reverts the commit you want to get rid of.

```
git revert sha-of-commit-to-get-rid-of
```

That should cause the creation of a compensating commit and you can push that to your branch. Merging that with Master will undo the changes in the commit you don't like.

If you really need to remove the current HEAD of master, you'll need (temporary) force-push permissions and the permission to bypass policies.

Comment: Thank you - also found this: https://opensource.com/article/18/6/git-reset-revert-rebase-commands

Comment: The article covers `revert`.

Comment: Yes, just remember that since `rebase` rewrites history on master, that can't be used for your Pull Request.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git revert` to revert an existing commit and record the changes in a new commit.
See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert.html

Comment: Thank you - found my answer before SO could come back... Taking @jessehouwing's answer as it contains the specific command I need.